# Prove $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right) = 0.$

Tags: calculus, limits

so I have to prove that $$\lim_{x\to 0}x^{2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right) = 0.$$

What I did is: $0 < |x| < \delta \implies \left|x^{2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\right| < \epsilon$

\begin{align*}
|x^2| &< \frac{\epsilon}{\cos(1/x^2)}\\
|x| &< \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\cos(1/x^2)}}
\end{align*}

So, $\delta = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\cos(1/x^2)}}$.

Is that right? I mean, did I do it all correct? Can I pass an $x$ to the other side? Or what am I supposed to do?
Thank you!

Comment: $|x^2 \cos(\frac{1}{x^2})| \leq |x^2|\cdot |\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})|$ and the cos is bounded by 1. so $|x^2|\cdot |\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})| \leq |x^2|$. And for small values of x it is true that $|x^2| \leq |x|$

Comment: No.  That is not right.  You have delta dependent upon x.  To know that x < some value dependent upon x, doesn't tell us anything about the *actual* value of x.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Consider $\lim_{x\rightarrow 7} x = 2,513$.  Because:  $|x-2513| < E$ means $0 < E-|x-2513|$ means $|x - 7| < E - |x-2513| + |x-7|$ so $d =  E - |x-2513| + |x-7|$.  QED. What you need to do instead is figure out a delta that is entirely dependent upon epsilon and not at all upon the x.  It really helps if you understand the *concept* of *why* delta epsilon proves actually work rather than viewing them as magical incantations of formulas to solve.

Comment: plot the function.

Comment: @fleablood: +1 for your comment. $\epsilon, \delta$ is not an exercise in algebraic manipulation of symbols. Rather one has to understand the nature of inequalities involved in the definition of limit and how $\epsilon, \delta $ are used to express these effectively.

Answer (score 3):

Let start by the well-known double inequality,

$$\forall x\ne 0 \;\;-1\le \cos(\frac {1}{x^2})\le 1$$

then after multiplication by $x^2$,

$$-x^2\le x^2\cos (\frac {1}{x^2})\le x^2$$

and by Squeeze theorem,

$$0\le \lim_{x\to 0}x^2\cos (\frac {1}{x^2})\le 0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Note that
$$
|x^{2}cos(1/x^{2})|\leq |x|^2.
$$
Hence, given $\varepsilon>0$, let $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$ and suppose $0<|x|<\delta.$ Then
$$
|x^{2}cos(1/x^{2})|\leq |x|^2<\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: I was told that, but I don't understand much of it. I'm really new to calculus, I'm just starting derivatives.

Comment: @Esteban: If you are new to calculus it is better to avoid any $\epsilon, \delta$ stuff. They are more of style than substance of calculus and are related to formalism not rigor.

Comment: Also using square roots is not needed because as soon as $|x|<1$ we have $|x^{2}|<|x|$ and we can thus take $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Oh, I was trying to understand it because the definition of limit is included on the exam. I don't think we have to prove a limit using the definition yet, but I was kind of beginning to understand the definition that way. Anyway, thanks a lot for your comment :)

Comment: @Esteban: BTW I was not trying to discourage you. In case you want to have a good understanding of $\epsilon, \delta $ definition of limit you need to look into some proofs of limit theorems. They are much better than those silly exercises which ask you to find limit via $\epsilon, \delta$.